Can I remove this center post?

I'm sure it's best to hire a pro to assess this, but thought I would ask. Do you all think it's safe to remove this center post? Just want to make sure it wouldn't cause any structural issues. This was a closet.  No second story or attic on the house.
There is no attic. it's just a flat roof that has gravel and all still on it and a pitched metal roof attached added atop. There is a small vent panel on the exterior. no real access to it.
There is a second piece of wood under that one which the post is in direct contact with, that piece of wood looks to not be secured that well. to me this just looks like basic framing for the closet components and not structural, but I am seriously no expert.

Can you get into the attic and draw a rough diagram of what’s on top of that post? Look particularly for overlapped ceiling joists.

The only issue with removing it, is how well the top plate is attached to the ceiling.  I do imagine the top plate is well attached, so that post is decoration.

@AloysiusDefenestrat no attic. it's just a flat roof that has gravel and all still on it and a pitched metal roof attached added atop. There is a small vent panel on the exterior. no real access to it.

@crip659 the top plate is the one directly incorporated into the ceiling and sheet rock? there is a second piece of wood under that one which the post is in direct contact with, that piece of wood looks to not be secured that well.  to me this just looks like basic framing for the closet components and not structural, but i am seriously no expert. lol

@KatyB all of that description belongs in the question ... it does not belong in comments ... comments are not considered to be a part of the question ... please use the edit button to update your question

It looks very much like the top plate and the post were added after construction of the ceiling, to frame closet doors.  The post could easily be much stronger, and would be if it needed to support the roof.  It looks, instead, like it was built to support lightweight door hinges and nothing more.
If you remove post you will have to remove the top plate, leaving ceiling damage and some minor damage to the walls on both sides.  You're going to have to do some patching and painting if you proceed with this.  So -- you may as well first carve out a little bit of the ceiling around the top plate, above the post, to see what framing is above it.  You have nothing to lose, and can confirm that there are no joist-ends meeting above this post.
